# A random variable $X$ has support in $[a,b]$, and $\mathbb{E}X=b$. Prove that $P(X\geq\mathbb{E}X)=1$

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $X$ be a discrete random variable such that $R(X) \subseteq I=[a,b]$, $-\infty<a<b<\infty$. Further let $\mathbb{P}$ be a probability measure. Is it possible to write for $x\in I$:  $\mathbb{P}[X\geq x]=\mathbb{P}[X> x] + \mathbb{P}[X=x]$? My Idea was to write $\{X\geq x\} = \{X>x\} \bigcup \{X=x\} $ and use the additivity of the probability measure.

Edit: The aim is to find a prove for the assertion, that if $\mathbb{E}[X]=b$, it follows that $\mathbb{P}[X\geq\mathbb{E}[X]]=1$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "My Idee was to write $\{X=x\}=\{X\leq x\} \bigcup \{X>x\} $" Absolutely sure about this identity?

Comment: Perhaps you mean $\{X=x\}=\{X\leqslant x\}\cap\{X\geqslant x\}$ or $\{X=x\}=\{X\leqslant x\}\setminus\{X < x\}$ instead?

Comment: Yes, of course. You're absolutely right.

Answer (score 2):

From your assumptions:

$$\max_{\omega \in \Omega} X(\omega) \leq b \;\rm{and}\; E[X]=\int_{\Omega} X(\omega)dP(\omega)=b \implies E\left[\frac{X(\omega)}{b}\right]=1$$

We can use the upper bound $b$ on $X$ to say:

$$ \frac{X(\omega)}{b}\leq 1\; \textrm{surely} \implies1=E\left[\frac{X(\omega)}{b}\right]=\int_{\Omega} \frac{X(\omega)}{b}dP(\omega)\leq \int_{\Omega} dP(\omega)= 1 $$

Therefore,

$$\int_{\Omega} \frac{X(\omega)}{b}dP(\omega) = 1 \implies \frac{X(\omega)}{b}= 1\; \textrm{a.s.} \implies P(X=b)=P(X=E[X])=1\implies P(X\geq E[X])=1 \;\textrm{by monotonicity of measure}:\{X=b\}\subset\{X\geq b\} $$

Answer (score 1):

Let's start out with your idea, namely that

$$\{X\geq b\} = \{X>b\}\cup (X=b),$$

where this union is disjoint. Then

$$P(X\geq b) = P(X > b) + P(X=b),$$

and since $R(X)\subseteq [a,b]$, we have $P(X>b)=0$, and thus

$$P(X\geq b) = P(X=b).$$

Now, by assumption, we have $\mathbb{E}[X] = b$. Then

$$b=\mathbb{E}[X]=\int_{\{X<b\}}X\ dP+\int_{\{X\geq b\}} X\ dP = \int_{\{X<b\}}X\ dP+ \int_{\{X=b\}} X\ dP,$$

where the last equality uses $P(X\geq b) = P(X=b)$. Notice how $X=b$ in the last integral. Thus

$$\int_{\{X=b\}} X\ dP = \int_{\{X=b\}} b\ dP = bP(X=b).$$

If you assume contrarywise that $P(X<b)>0$, then the calculation of the mean value amounts to

$$b = \int_{\{X<b\}}X\ dP+bP(X=b)<\int_{\{X<b\}}b\ dP+bP(X=b)=bP(X<b)+bP(x=b)=bP(X\leq b) = b.$$

It reads that $b<b$, which is a contradiction. Thus $P(X<b) = 0$, and then $P(X\geq b) = 1$ (which is incidentally equal to $P(X=b)$).